# Loop condition for accessing all of a List's Nodes

Tags: java, list, data-structures, nodes

```
for(int i=1;i<list.size();i++) 
{
    if (x.nextNode!=null) 
    {
        if (x.data=='C') 
        {
            x.data='G';
        } else if (x.data=='G') {
            x.data='C';
        } else if (x.data=='A') {
            x.data='T';
        } else if (x.data=='T') {
            x.data='A';
        }       
    } 
    x=x.nextNode;
}
```

I have created a list with char Nodes which only contains `A G C T` and a loop which checks every Node of the list and changes it. G should be changed to C, C should be changed to G, A should be changed to T, T should be changed to A.

My problem is that every `Node.char` item is changed except for the last Node of the list. How I should edit this code to also change the last Node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are starting from `1` so apparently skipping one node. so to traverse whole `LinkList` (seems like) you should to start from `0`

```
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
 //       ^
```

**update** : when `if (x.nextNode!=null)` is `false` mean you have reached the last node.

`if (lastNode.nextNode!=null)` will be `false` so no execution will take place ,so to execute the last node , use

```
if (x!=null)
```

Comment: still , the last's Node character doesn't get changed